# I use gem 'turbolinks'. When you update the page, editor is displayed once. When you load the page editor, the panel is displayed twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

The problem with turbolinks. When you update the page, editor is displayed once. When you load the page editor, the panel is displayed twice.

I use `gem 'bootsy'`.

`gem 'turbolinks' -v '2.2.0`.

This problem is observed in Google Chrome. For example, in Firefox, everything looks fine.

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery.textchange
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootsy
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
```

I tried to use this solution:

```
$(document).addEventListener("page:load", function(){
  Bootsy.init();
});
```

But no change.

I tried to use this solution:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery.textchange
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootsy
//= require bootstrap
$(function() {
  Bootsy.init();
});
//= require turbolinks
```

And it helped, but I think it's wrong. Can anyone else faced this problem?

Comment: `$(document)` is jQuery code ($ is jQuery default selector), and `addEventListener` is not a jQuery function. Try using `$(document).on('page:load', function(){ Boosty.init() } )` -- You might also need to put `$(document).ready( function (){ Bootsy.init() })` for the requests not using Turbolink

Comment: @MrYoshiji also not helped, in the browser console here is a log:
`XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/admin/campaigns/new"`

Answer (score 0):

Move your javascript includes inside . Or add `data-turbolinks-eval="false"` to your scripts, [docs](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#evaluating-script-tags)